# Postpending addition persistently to $PATH in zsh with line in .zshrc

Tags: zsh

I have an directory on my $PATH that I need to remain in first position . I added a new directory to my $PATH via the entry

`export PATH="/home/me/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish:$PATH"`

This prepends the new directory to the $PATH. I would like to post pend this new directory to $PATH  and need this change to be persistent through log out/log in, power off/power on cycles.

I tried the command
`path+=("~/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish")`
this did postpend the directory but was not persistent
Likewise:
`path+=~/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish`
`path+=/home/me/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish`
The research I did seemed to suggest that the `path+=` command should be persistent but in my case it wasn't. I am also using Oh-my-zsh but as I could find out this shouldn't affect changed to $PATH made from the CLI or via .zshrc.

Comment: A `~` inside double quoted strings does not expand. Aside from this: To put a directory in front of the others, do a `path=( NEWDIRECTORY  $path )`.

Comment: @user1934428  to clarify: my $PATH looks like this (as an example) `/home/dir1: /home/dir2:/home/dir3:/home/dir4` . Where I want to move dir1 to the position of dir4 or the last directory on `$PATH`  . Is there a way to do this in zsh?

Comment: To add a line to ~/.zshrc to append your path to $PATH and make it persist: `printf "\n%s\n" 'export PATH="${PATH:+${PATH}:}$HOME/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish"' >> ~/.zshrc` and restart Terminal.

Comment: @ajr_chm : there is a space in front of `/home/dir2`, so the PATH looks wrong. BTW, instead of fiddling with the scalar `PATH`, it is usually more convenient to modify the array `path`. And, modifying the .zshrc using `printf`, as Aeronautix is suggesting,  is IMHO insane. We usually use a text editor for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your text editor on your ~/.zshrc. To append your directory to the path,  do a

```
path+=~me/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish
```

If you want to replace the last element in your path by a new one, do a

```
path[-1]=~me/Tresors/my_tresor/ClientFilter/publish
```

Explanation:

`path` is an array which is coupled to `PATH`. With `+=`, you append a new element to the array. Indexing with a negative index refers to index positions from the end of the array.